# x-systemd.automount & CIFS shares in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, cifs

In my `/etc/fstab`, I have set up a few CIFS shares to be mounted, using the template shown below:

```
//192.168.0.1/volume /mnt/mountpoint/ cifs auto,_netdev,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,cache=none,user=XXX,password=XXX,workgroup=WORKGROUP 0 0
```

I copied the same lines to my colleague's computer (we are both running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS); however, the shares wouldn't mount on his computer until I removed the `x-systemd.automount` option.

As I'd like to understand the problem, could you please let me know what might have caused it?

Comment: I'm not a Ubunut user but I think Ubuntu moved to systemd. the x-systemd.automount should work  with the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't use systemd, so x-systemd.automount won't work. I guess it is just interpreted as an invalid mount option.

If you want to have your CIFS share mounted on-demand have a look at this: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Autofs

Comment: Hi!, you should update your answer because Ubuntu 16.04 already supports systemd, and therefore thet option x-systemd.automount  will work. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/systemd.mount.5.html

Answer (score 25):

**systemd was introduced in ubuntu 15.04.**

After adding `x-systemd.automount` to an `fstab` line, you need to run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then one, or both, of the following:

```
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

only then will the automount become active.

Comment: This works great. You can also add `x-systemd.device-timeout=10` to your fstab line for a timeout limit.